# Wordpress loop is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, blogs

Can anyone tell me why this wordpress blog is looping the header and banner over and over?  It seems like instead of just looping the post it is looping the whole page.

Here is a link to my blog:
http://testing.printlabelandmail.com/blog/

```
<?php
/**
* The default template for displaying content.
*/
get_header(); ?>

<!-- Start Top Header affix nav-->
<div id="affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="94" data-offset-bottom="0">

<!-- **** START - NAVBAR SCROLLSPY FIX DO NOT REMOVE **** 
<div id="top" class="hide"></div>
<!-- **** END - NAVBAR SCROLLSPY FIX DO NOT REMOVE **** -->

<!-- **** START - NAV **** -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-shrink">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<!-- main-logo goes here-->
<h1 class="brand--font"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?   >">        PRINTLABELANDMAIL.COM</a></h1>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-    target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="icon-menu"></span>
    </button>
            </div>
<!-- **** START - NAVBAR SCROLLSPY FIX DO NOT REMOVE **** -->
<li class="hide"><a href="#top"></a></li>
<!-- **** END - NAVBAR SCROLLSPY FIX DO NOT REMOVE **** -->
<?php

$defaults = array(
'theme_location'  => '',
'menu'            => 'main-nav',
'container_id'    => 'nav',
'container_class' => 'navbar navbar-default navbar-shrink',
'container'       => 'div',
'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse',
'container_id'    => '',
'menu_class'      => 'menu',
'menu_id'         => '',
'echo'            => true,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'before'          => '',
'after'           => '',
'link_before'     => '',
'link_after'      => '',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
'depth'           => 0,
'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
        </div>
    </nav><!-- **** END - NAV **** -->
</div><!-- **** END -affix NAV **** -->
<!-- end Top Header affix nav-->

<!-- **** start blog banner **** -->    
<div id="blog-banner">

<?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('blog-banner')) :     else : ?>
<div class="pre-widget">
    <p><strong>Widgetized Area</strong></p>
    <p>This panel is active and ready for you to add some widgets via the WP  Admin</p>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<!-- **** / end blog banner **** -->    

<!-- **** START - BLOG **** -->
<div class="container  blog">
  <div class="row  blog--row">

    <!-- **** START - LEFT CONTENT -->
    <div class="col-lg-8">

      <!-- blog post -->
<!-- blog post -->
<article <?php post_class('box  box--md  blog--post  push--bottom-sml'); ?>>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive push--bottom')); ?>

<h3 class="brand--font-standard"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<h5 class="brand--font-light"><?php _e('posted by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?></h5>

<ul class="list-inline  tags  blog--tags  push--bottom-tiny">             
<li><?php the_category(',') ?></li>
</ul>

<?php the_content('<p class="section-subtitle"><p class="btn  btn--orange  brand-- font">Read More</p></p>'); ?>

<?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> 

<?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
</article>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!-- pagination -->
<ul class="pagination">
            <li class="disabled  pagination--prev"><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li class="pagination--next"><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
          </ul><!-- pagination -->
        </div>
      </div>
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="pagination--prev"><?php previous_post_link('<< %link') ?></li> <li     class="pagination--next"><?php next_post_link(' %link >>') ?></li>
          </ul>
</div><!-- **** END - LEFT CONTENT **** -->

<!-- **** START - RIGHT CONTENT **** -->
    <div class="col-lg-4  right-hand-bar">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- **** END - RIGHT CONTENT **** -->
</div>
</div><!-- **** END - BLOG **** -->
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. You did not even tell us the name of the .php file you are showing us. How are we supposed to tell you anything when file names are a major part of WordPress templating conventions?

Comment: I apologize, this is a totally new theme I am building from scratch and the current file this code is in is content.php

Comment: Given there's no loops in this code at all (for, while, do/while, etc...) we can't help you.

Comment: Okay, I thought that I had specified a loop, the reason why is because I am seeing post content.  Can you direct me towards writing up the proper loop?

Comment: There's a pretty complete official guide on WP templating: http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates Either try and pinpoint the problem yourself, maybe post some relevant code here so we can help, or start reading the docs until you find the problem yourself. Right now there's no way we could help you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better fit for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

is that correct?? please double check

```
  <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('blog-banner')) :     else : ?>

//i think i should be like below:

 <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('blog-banner')) dynamic_sidebar( 'blog-banner' );  else : ?>
```

Comment: Checking out the generated HTML on his live server one can see this is not an issue. Maybe it's a typo in the question, but nothing more.